# h.264/svc mobile support

Tags: mobile, h.264

I am new to H.264/SVC standard. I researched and found out that mobile devices such as android, ipad and iOSx support H.264/AVC. Since, H.264/SVC is the extension of the H.264/AVC with the multilayered structure for base profile and enhanced profile, I was wondering if the devices that support H.264/AVC also support H.264/SVC or not?

Comment: Ogg Vorbis and H.264 should be supported on a website.

Comment: @Cole Johnson: Ogg is a container format; Vorbis is an audio codec. H.264 is a video codec. This question is about video.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From my (merely theoretical) research of the matter, an H.264 AVC player will NOT be able to decode an H.264 SVC stream out of the box.

But using SVC as the encoding format on your server does not necessarily mean that you stream the SVC encoded data to your clients. The transformation from SVC to AVC can be done server-side with very little computational effort. It is NOT a re-encoding! There is an increasing number of solutions in the market that use the H.264 SVC file format on the server but still send AVC streams with tailored data rates to their clients after determining the available network bandwidth. This way the streaming system stays compatible with the existing client base but can already use the advantages of SVC on the servers (e.g. only one file per video and a very low storage overhead).

On the other hand it is indeed possible to send streams in SVC format if your clients are capable of processing them. If needed these SVC streams can have a reduced data rate - depending on available bandwidth - which can be extracted from the original SVC file easily and with low computing power by dropping SVC layers. Rebuilding the stream on the fly and sending a reduced layer set (down to the simple base layer) will make sense in many scenarios, whenever the available bandwidth does not allow to stream the full SVC file. After all this is what SVC is all about: The possibility to quickly generate reduced bandwidth versions from a single master file or high bandwidth SVC stream.

Actually dropping layers from SVC streams can even take place on the fly at specialized intermediate network nodes and proxies on the way from the server to the client. This allows to reduce the signal data rate whenever the following section of the network connection has a bandwidth that is to low for the full incoming stream.

Some providers that I found for systems that generate adapted SVC or AVC streams from SVC files on the fly are

- [Radvision](http://www.radvision.com/Solutions/Video-Communications-Technology/Scalable-Video-Coding/) (video conferencing),
- [Vidyo](http://www.vidyo.com/technology/) (video conferencing) and
- [Stretch](http://search.stretchinc.com/search?q=svc&Submit.x=-717&Submit.y=-60&Submit=GO&site=Stretchinc&client=Stretchinc&proxystylesheet=Stretchinc&output=xml_no_dtd) (video hardware).

For some more details on H.264 SVC see these links:

- http://www.streaminglearningcenter.com/articles/h264--scalable-video-coding---what-you-need-to-know.html
- http://www.eetimes.com/design/signal-processing-dsp/4017613/Tutorial-The-H-264-Scalable-Video-Codec-SVC-?pageNumber=0.

Comment: I am currently researching the matter myself. So I have just upgraded my answer "a bit" with new findings. :)